# What does "MEDIAN SESSION LENGTH" mean in Company Activity Dashboard #flurry?

Tags: session, median, flurry

What does "MEDIAN SESSION LENGTH" mean and how its value extracted?

If the time range is fix then how the median value will be changing?

Answer (score 0):

The median session length is the median value of all of the session lengths logged during the time frame, where the median is the "middle" value in a list of numbers organized from smallest to largest.